# Assigning a Floating IP to a Load Balancer in a heat template

Tags: openstack, heat, openstack-nova

Does anyone know how to associate a floating IP address with a load balancer in a heat template? I can create a load balancer on an instance (or a bunch of instances, but starting small) in heat; and can associate a floating IP address to the load balancer in Horizon, but I can't figure out how to do it through heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to find the answer to this question myself.

It turns out that the `vip` attribute of an `OS::Neutron::Pool` resource contains a few more keys than are documented [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/heat/template_guide/openstack.html#OS::Neutron::Pool-hot).  In particular, the `vip` attribute contains a `port_id`, which is the address of the Neutron port associated with this pool.

Since we have a Neutron port id, we can use that to associate a floating ip address like this:

```
type: "OS::Neutron::Pool"
  properties:
    protocol: HTTP
    monitors:
      - {get_resource: monitor}
    subnet_id: {get_resource: fixed_subnet}
    lb_method: ROUND_ROBIN
    vip:
      protocol_port: 80

lb_floating:
  type: "OS::Neutron::FloatingIP"
  properties:
    floating_network_id:
      get_param: external_network_id
    port_id:
      get_attr: [pool, vip, port_id]
```

That `get_attr` call is getting the `port_id` attribute of the `vip` attribute of the `pool` resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question in regard to Octavia rather then Neutron, however Larsks answer did point me in the right direction.

The `OS::Octavia::LoadBalancer` object has a `vip_port_id` attribute which can be accessed in the same way:

```
  port_id:
    get_attr: [lb1, vip_port_id]
```